# Dataframe for Apriori algorithm | Market Basket Analysis in R

Tags: r, apriori

I will be grateful if somebody could tell me what am I missing in my code. I am trying to find association rules using apriori algorithm (arules package) in R. I am using R-3.2 version for MacOSX.

The problem arises when I am reading the dataset from a csv format into a transactions class object. I am using the following piece of code -

```
>Transac1 <- read.transactions(file="transactions.csv", format = "basket", sep=";", rm.duplicates=TRUE)
```

On inspecting the data frame, I am observing that the first element in all the rows is missing.

```
>inspect(Transac1[1:5])

items        
1  {,           
Milk}    
2  {,           
Shoes}    
3  {,           
Talc}   
4  {,           
Cable}     
5  {,           
Shoe Polish, Talc}
```

I am able to generate association rules in the end, but I think those are not correct (just because of these blank elements). Can anyone understand and tell me what is possibly the reason for this? The file that I use for reading has data in the requisite format for apriori algorithm.

Any leads would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

@user2031612 please write your code when run apriori algorithm in R, because i have meet same problem because, it's my mistake when not set `minLen` parameter, you should tried put parameter `minLen = 2`. It will produce rule with no blank elements